# is there any auto backup of mysql database?

Tags: mysql, backup

Unfortunately I have lost some part of my data (a field of table) in a mysql database on a linux server
and my backup is old

I want to know is there any solution to recover that table?

Comment: `I want to know is there any solution to recover that table?` Do you have an Eidetic memory and decent WPM typing skills?

Comment: No. unfortunately not

Comment: why negative points!!!!

Comment: You deployed an application without bothering to set up backups. *Professional* System Administration is what [sf] is about. This shouldn't be a surprise to you. And I won't even get into the fact that you didn't supply any examples of what you tried nor did you apparently do any research.

Comment: @Magellan thank you, I've heard similar words before,  you maybe are right. certainly i did research and found nothing. if I could simply solve the problem I wouldn't post it here. I searched in the site and nothing was about recovery or undo or restore of a lost table in mysql. Yes I had to backup but if I had backuped on a daily base, it was still possible to loss the data after the last backup. I thought maybe like many other critical software mysql have a help or solution. but all is ok

Answer (score 4):

Not unless you configured one.  Sorry, but your data is gone.

(And not to kick you while you're down, but this is why regular, working, restore-tested backups matter.  Make sure to learn your lesson from this and get your backups in order ASAP.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting the database yourself or are you going through a hosting provider? Many hosting providers provide daily database backups that you may be able to use to recover a more recent version of the database.

In the future you could set up a Cron task to automatically make these backups for you.

Comment: I  am hosting the database. Now I scheduled an automatic backup with Webmin.

Comment: It seems I have lost the data and there is no way back.